# What is use of function mnist.train.next_batch() in training dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow for training my own dataset using capsule network. While training mnist dataset, it contains function mnist.train.next_batch(batch size). How to replace this function for training own dataset using TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

The function sample `batch_size` number of samples from a shuffled training dataset, then return the batch for training.

You could write your own `next_batch()` method that does the same thing, or modify it as you wish. Then use it similarly when you're training your model.

Comment: Is it necessory to sample randomly because in that case training images may repeated. Is there any way to sequentially sample batch_size number of images?

Comment: It does sequentially not random. It reshuffles the examples after going through all of them every epoch. Implementation is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c36309c37b04843030664cdc64aca2bb7d6ecaa/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160)

Comment: @AnushaMehta yeah it's shuffle and sample, sort of 'random' I'll edit my answer

Comment: @ARAT In the implementation, the function parameter 'self' refer to what?

Comment: It is a keyword/variable in Python. It is used to refer to instance variables. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) for more information.